# How to create a matrix in Excel?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have some data that looks a bit like this:

| Value_1 | Value_2 | Value_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | TRUE | FALSE |
| TRUE | TRUE | FALSE |
| TRUE | FALSE | TRUE |

I want to create a matrix which counts the number of times each combination of two values are flagged as true on the same row. So the required output should look like this:

|  | Value_1 | Value_2 | Value_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Value_1 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| Value_2 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| Value_3 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Does anyone know how best to do this please? I've been fiddling around with pivot tables but haven't managed to make one that works as required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Dynamic array formulas, this will spill:

```
=MMULT(--TRANSPOSE(A2:C4),--A2:C4)
```

[image]

This is just matrix multiplication, but first the `--` (double unary) converts the `TRUE` and `FALSE` to `1` and `0`. Here's an example of the calculation of the `3`.

[image]

---

Another option using `SUM` and `INDEX`/`MATCH` that can be dragged across and down.

```
=SUM(INDEX($A$2:$C$4,,MATCH(F$1,$A$1:$C$1,0))*INDEX($A$2:$C$4,,MATCH($E2,$A$1:$C$1,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @BigBen - the first method worked. Could you explain what exactly it's doing though please? I've been googling the mmult formula and all I'm getting is results telling me it's multiplying my original data with the transposed version of it. I'm admittedly no mathematician, but I can't wrap my head around what it's multiplying with what to get the correct results?

Comment: I've edited with some more detail.